# ASP.NET MVC Identity, authorize pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identity

I want to authorize the Identity folder, but let registration be allowed for anonymous.

My code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", p => p.RequireRole(Roles.Administrator));
    options.AddPolicy("Employee", p => p.RequireRole(Roles.Employee));
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/", "Admin");

    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Register");
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Login");
});
```

When I try it shows

> This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7247/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FRegister
> HTTP ERROR 404

And has this url in broswer:

```
https://localhost:7247/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FRegister
```

I think it something wrong with `AllowAnonymousToPage`, it does not make them anonymous...

Answer (score 0):

According the error message, you should change your code like below.

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/", "Admin");
    
    // Allow anonymous access to the Register and Login pages
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Identity/Account/Register");
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Identity/Account/Login");
});
```